# 2 _ _ _ _ 2 _ 7 _ 2 is a multiple of $396,533$, find the missing numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I was doing a maths crossword, and the clue is ‘a multiple of $396,533$‘, and I have filled out the numbers shown in the title. How would you go about doing this sort of problem. I have worked out the multiplier is approximately between 5000 and 8000 and the last digit is a 4 (probably), and then just used trial and error from there, but came up empty handed. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: A quick for loop in javascript yields two results: `for (x=5004;x<8004;x+=10){
num = '' + (x*396533);
if (num.substr(0,1) == '2' && num.substr(5,1)=='2' && num.substr(7,1) == '7'){console.log(num)}}` yielded $2844727742$ and $2856623732$.  Note that we didn't bother checking the last digit since as you noticed, the last digit of the multiplier must indeed by $4$ (*seen by an easy mod10 argument*) so we got to iterate by $10$ each time.  Further, as you correctly noticed, to have the first digit and number of digits match the multiplier will indeed be between $5000$ and $8000$.

Comment: My thought would be to figure out the possibilities for the last 3 digits, given that the number ends in 7_2. Since 396533 is relatively prime to 1000, there are 10 possibilities, one for each digit. At least, that cuts down the search space.